# Enter the URL to jump to another page, change how you do it

Tags: php

for examble

enter `http://111.111.111.111/aaa.co.uk/web/`

default jump to

```
http://111.111.111.111/aaa.co.uk/web/upload.html
```

**how you do it?**

i try to do like this

modify .htacess

```
Redirect /aaa.co.uk/web/ /aaa.co.uk/web/upload.html
```

but url address show

```
http://111.111.111.111/aaa.co.uk/web/upload.html/upload.html/upload.html/upload.html/upload.html/upload.html/upload.html/upload.html/upload.html/upload.html/upload.html
......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it need to be .htaccess?

So for the page:

```
http://111.111.111.111/aaa.co.uk/web/
```

Where the index.php file for that page can have:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://111.111.111.111/aaa.co.uk/web/upload.html");
exit;
```

**Edit**

If it needs to be .htaccess, perhaps something like the below?

```
RewriteRule ^/aaa\.co\.uk/web/$ /aaa\.co\.uk/web/upload\.html [R=301,L]
```

Note the delimiters and the 301, permanent redirect rule.

Answer (score 2):

Try this .htaccess

```
Redirect /aaa.co.uk/web/$ /aaa.co.uk/web/upload.html
```

The `$` tell apache only to redirect `/aaa.co.uk/web` and not everthing starting with that string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Header()` function, its goes like that:

```
Header("Location: yourredirecturl.php");
die();
```

you can also add

```
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
```

before the `die();` it will return header of 301, check it out if you should redirect for permanently or temporary (SEO issues).